# Bottle 0.8.0: What does this route specification mean?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bottle

In this bit of code,

```
def setRoute(route, method='GET'):
    def decorator(f):
        f.route=route
        f.method=method
        return f
    return decorator
...

class MyClass:

    @setRoute( '/:action#.*#',method='POST' )
    def acceptMessage( self, action ):
        ...
```

What does `#.*#` mean?

Is it an old syntax? Because I can't find it in current [bottle documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/routing.html).

Comment: :name#regexp# => <name:re:regexp>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the old syntax for a named regular expression route. See [this paragraph](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/routing.html#legacy-syntax).

Comment: Oh, I have been blind! Thanks